# Looking at old logs on Heroku

Tags: heroku, logging

I have a Ruby heroku app. It crashed. I rebooted it, it works. Fine. Such is the life of a computer program.

Now, I want to look at the error logs to see WHY it crashed. However, when I go to view logs, they start at the reboot. How do I find the logs from 30 minutes ago when the app crashed?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that restarting an instance clears all logs so it's best to do this with care.

If you'd like to store logs long-term, look at implementing [Log Drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains)

Comment: I should look into that. thanks... IT's unfortunate when it's the production server, and you need to restart because people are USING it, but then you lose the evidence to figure out what actually HAPPENED... *sigh*